# If statement does not avoid insert query

Tags: php, mysql, http

I'm trying to create a simple api, which is suppose to add views to different news from a mobile application. When i test this directly in the browser using a url like:

http://url/addview.php?type=ios&identifier=35605C24-8EA6-4342-Bdfd-245432&newsid=147

Here it works and does add duplicates if news_id, type and identifier already exist. However when i run this url through asynchronous http request in my ios application it seem to always add a new record even though it already exist in the d

```
$con = new mysqli('host','user','pass','db');
$type = $_GET['type'];
$identifier = $_GET['identifier'];
$news = $_GET['newsid'];

$check = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM views WHERE views.news_id =? AND views.type =? AND views.identifier=?");
$check->bind_param("iss", $news, $type, $identifier);
$check->execute();
$check->store_result();
$check->fetch(); 

if ($check->num_rows == 0) {
    $con->next_result();
    $check->close();
    $add_view = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO views (views.news_id, views.type, views.identifier, views.reg_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())");
    $add_view->bind_param("iss", $news, $type, $identifier);
    $add_view->execute();
    $add_view->close();
    $con->next_result();


}

$con->close();
```

Comment: Instead of 2 querys, why not add a `UNIQUE KEY(views.news_id, views.type, views.identifier)` on your table and then just do a single query - `INSERT INGORE ...`?

Comment: could u make a answer? i'm not sure i understand?

Comment: a `unique` constraint will cause the database to reject any new row which conflicts with the restraint.

Comment: try to remove `$check->fetch();` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want duplicates, then add an appropriate unique index.  Based on your logic, I think this would be:

```
create unique index idx_views_3 on views(news_id, type, identifier);
```

Then, do the insert as:

```
INSERT INTO views (news_id, type, identifier, reg_date)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
    on duplicate key update news_id = values(news_id);
```

Comment: On duplicate it should not update. is this query doing that :) ?

Comment: @PeterPik . . . The `on duplicate key update` clause is a no-op.  It updates the value of `news_id` to the same value it already is.  MySQL ignores such updates, so nothing actually happens, except a wee amount of work to check that the value isn't changing.